# Invoke-command still using my PC as middle man during robocopy?

Tags: command-line, powershell, robocopy

Can someone look at my code and tell me why when using invoke-command, that my PC is still being used as a middle-man?

I'm trying to get the destination computer to transfer directly and not use my PC as the middle man.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Credential $creds -Authentication Credssp -ScriptBlock {    
    robocopy \\$($args[0])\C$\usmt \\$($args[1])\C$\usmt /E /COPY:DATOU /E /ZB /mt:32 /r:5 /w:0
}-ArgumentList $SourceComputer,$DestinationComputer -ErrorAction Inquire
```

Comment: Huh, say what? You're using a credential apparently so it's authenticated to the resources for source and destination per RoboCopy. What is your concern exactly?

Comment: I want to transfer directly from source to destination and not use my PC as "file handler." It is doing this even though all of them are connected to same switch.

Comment: @ChristopherHeisler This part `\\$($args[0])\C$\usmt \\$($args[1])\C$\usmt` tells you that files are being transfered beteween the other machines, which is what you are asking. If you want to take off your machine from this process, you need to execute a script like that on the source, or destination, given you have permission and access to either one of those machines

Comment: Doesn't "Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DestinationComputer" mean I'm running the command on the destination machine?
Should I try adding an invoke-expression right before robocopy?

Comment: This is just a small part of the script. The process being executed is robocopy which is built into all of the machine. I'm using invoke-command to tell the Destination Computer to start a robocopy. It does not matter WHERE this script is executed from. I'm not running into any error. The problem is that for some stupid reason my computer is still being used as a middleman for the transfer. Probably should just use copy-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are running the process `ROBOCOPY` on that computer with `$DestinationComputer`, yes. But you still are running `Invoke-Command` on your machine which waits for `stdout` and `stderr`.

From the docs

> The Invoke-Command cmdlet runs commands on a local or remote computer
>   and returns all output from the commands, including errors

So this behavior is expected with your code

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DestinationComputer -Credential $creds -Authentication 
Credssp -ScriptBlock {    
    robocopy \\$($args[0])\C$\usmt \\$($args[1])\C$\usmt /E /COPY:DATOU /E /ZB /mt:32 
/r:5 /w:0
}-ArgumentList $SourceComputer,$DestinationComputer -ErrorAction Inquire
```

What you need is to pass the the `InDisconnectedSession` option. Which makes `Invoke-Command` to connect, run cmd and disconnect promptly. Again from the docs:

> To create a disconnected session, use the InDisconnectedSession
>   parameter of the Invoke-Command cmdlet. It creates a session, starts
>   the command, and disconnects immediately, before the command can
>   return any output.

This is what you are asking for.

Cheers.